# Installation of tidyverse

Tags: r

I am trying to install tidyverse using R console.

I used the following code:

```
install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")
```

The whole error during installation is below:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ps_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 261887 bytes (255 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 255 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/processx_3.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 123430 bytes (120 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 120 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/callr_3.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94264 bytes (92 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 92 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/fs_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 812680 bytes (793 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 793 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reprex_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1052597 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ps’ ...
** package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -Wall px.c -o px
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___error", referenced from:
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "___stderrp", referenced from:
      _usage in px-c5af23.o
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _write_to_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "___stdoutp", referenced from:
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_close", referenced from:
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
  "_exit", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
  "_fflush", referenced from:
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_fprintf", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _write_to_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_fputs", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_fwrite", referenced from:
      _usage in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_getenv", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_open", referenced from:
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_puts", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_read", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
  "_sleep", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_sscanf", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_strcmp", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_strerror", referenced from:
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
  "_strlen", referenced from:
      _write_to_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_usleep", referenced from:
      _main in px-c5af23.o
  "_write", referenced from:
      _cat2 in px-c5af23.o
      _cat in px-c5af23.o
      _write_to_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _echo_from_fd in px-c5af23.o
      _main in px-c5af23.o
     (maybe you meant: _write_to_fd)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makevars:11: px] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ps’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/ps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘fs’ ...
** package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c error.cc -o error.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c dir.cc -o dir.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c utils.cc -o utils.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c link.cc -o link.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c path.cc -o path.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c file.cc -o file.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fs.cc -o fs.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c id.cc -o id.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c unix/getmode.cc -o unix/getmode.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++  -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
cp -p -f libuv/m4/lt_obsolete.m4 libuv/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
(cd libuv \
    && touch aclocal.m4 \
    && touch -r aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.in \
&& CC="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang" CFLAGS="-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -fPIC " AR="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar" RANLIB="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/anaconda3/lib -L/anaconda3/lib" ./configure --quiet)
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/p0/v1gbs0_s2dj_4mb124rln5r00000gn/T/RtmpBWlBiC/R.INSTALL134c03ff68e2a/fs/src/libuv':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [Makevars:32: libuv/Makefile] Error 77
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fs’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/fs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ps’ is not available for package ‘processx’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/processx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available for package ‘callr’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/callr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘callr’, ‘fs’ are not available for package ‘reprex’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/reprex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘reprex’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/p0/v1gbs0_s2dj_4mb124rln5r00000gn/T/RtmpeB0Fy8/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I then used `> library(tidyverse)`
and encountered this:

> Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Comment: `tidyverse` is a package collection which imports tonnes of packages. Have you tried installing `dplyr`, `tidyr` or another `tidyverse` separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running R from anaconda (since I observe things are getting removed from your anaconda3 lib), you can try to go to the anaconda prompt and use conda commands, here's the instructions:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/r-language-pkg-docs/

You are restricted, I believe,  to the version of tidyverse which is supported by Anaconda which can be found here:
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/

Perhaps that solves your issue.